# Extract String from between 2 Strings with Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, string

How do I extract '**inc/funcs.asp**' from the string below, with Jquery or Javascript.

```
<script>
 var str = '<!-- #include file="inc/funcs.asp" -->';  
</script>
```

I imagine the pattern must start with looking for '#include file="'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/file="([^"]+)/
```

and grab captured group #1

Code:

```
var fval = (str.match(/file="([^"]+)/) || ['', ''])[1];
```

Comment: Interesting, I see your logic, by grabbing out what's between the double quotes. I was originally going for a more complicated approach.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var text = '<!-- #include file="inc/funcs.asp" -->';
var str = text.match(/"(.*?)"/);
alert(str[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '<!-- #include file="inc/funcs.asp" -->';  
str.match(/\"(.+)\"/)[1];
```

returns "inc/funcs.asp"