# Javascript Regular Expression Whitespace Detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, whitespace

I submitted this [Extract String RegEx Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524658/extract-string-from-between-2-strings-with-jquery) post not too long ago.
I want to enhance the expression pattern more.

So far this works nicely:

```
<script> 
  // extract the inc/funcs.asp from the variable.
  var text = '<!-- #include file="inc/funcs.asp" -->'; 
  var pattern = /file="([^"]+)/i
  var result = (text.match(pattern) || ['', ''])[1]; 
  console.log(result); // returns: inc/funcs.asp
</script>
```

I'm now testing white-space nuances.
The pattern I'm applying is: /file="([^"]+)/i
I'd like to add more to this pattern.

For example:

```
var pattern = /#include file="([^"]+)/i
```

And this works, unless there's more space between the **#include** and **file**.

So I altered the pattern to this:

```
var pattern = /#include(\s+)file="([^"]+)/i
```

Full Script:

```
<script>
  var text = '<!-- #Include      File="inc/funcs.asp" -->'; 
  var pattern = /#include(\s+)file="([^"]+)/i 
  var result = (text.match(pattern) || ['', ''])[1]; 
  var count = result.length; 

  if(count > 0){ 
    console.log(result); 
  }
</script>
```

The **count** variable is greater than 0, and runs the `console.log`.
But the variable **result** is empty.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the capturing group - `()` of `\s+` from `regex`. Otherwise, it'll always return spaces in `result` array.

```
var pattern = /#include\s+file="([^"]+)/i;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6be81wq2/)

```js
var text = '<!-- #Include      File="inc/funcs.asp" -->';
var pattern = /#include\s+file="([^"]+)/i;
var result = (text.match(pattern) || ['', ''])[1];

if (result.length > 0) {
  alert(result);
}
```

Comment: That was it! I will need to understand capturing groups more now.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you added a group, and the element at index `1` in the array returned by `match` is this group (full of spaces).

Change

```
var pattern = /#include(\s+)file="([^"]+)/i
```

to

```
var pattern = /#include\s+file="([^"]+)/i
```

An alternative would have been to use a non remembered group (`(?:\s+)`) but you don't need a group at all.